# How to create New Rdd with all possible combination of elements other Rdd in spark java implementation?

Tags: java, apache-spark

If RDD1 = [p,k,t]
Now I want to create new RDD2 with all possible combinations like below with new RDD of length k .i.e.except same element combination like(p,p),(k,k),(t,t).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cartesian join can be used with filter:

```
    List<String> data = Lists.newArrayList("p", "k", "t");
    final JavaRDD<String> values = jsc().parallelize(data);
    final JavaPairRDD<String, String> result = values
            .cartesian(values)
            .filter(kv -> kv._1 != kv._2);
```

Output:

```
(p,k)
(p,t)
(k,p)
(k,t)
(t,k)
(t,p)
```